# Is there a difference between the meanings of 'is a result of' and 'results from'?

Tags: grammar

I'm searching on the internet how to use *result from*, and I've found the examples:

> His failure is a result of laziness.
>
> His failure results from his laziness.

[Wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/be-resulted-from.3277949/).

Are both correct? Is there a slight difference in meaning?

Comment: Your title asks a different question from the body of your question—which is it?

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible. I'd have rather said (AE speaker)

"His failure is a result of his laziness"

The 2nd option you list (results from) is correct but isn't great and refers to something general, not a specific instance of failure.

Comment: Thank you very much I have another one question. The destruction of the rain forests is resulted from slash-and-burn agriculture. This sentence is correct?

Comment: No. You want to say: "The destruction of the rain forest is the result of slash-and-burn agriculture" but that's not really accurate because it means 100% of the destruction is a result of that one thing, which can't be true.